# Apply different PlotStyles to functions with functions as variable

Tags: plotting, variable

I have a function `func[expr,var]` with which I want to plot the list `expr[var]` and have different styles applied to it. When doing this with `ListPlot`, it works, but somehow this just gives the plot with the first `PlotStyle` given.

To be specific:

`func[expr_, var_] := 
    Module[{f}, f[x_] := Evaluate[expr /. var -> x]; 
    Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {{Red}, {Black}}]]`

This gives the plot of `Sin[x]` and `Sin[2x]` both in red. How do I get one the first expression in red and the second in black?

Comment: Why not just `func[expr_, var_] := Plot[expr, {var, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {{Red}, {Black}}]`?

Comment: True :'D
I must've somehow come to the conclusion that this would not work for some reason. Now I changed quite a bit in the structure and this seems to work again. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep `f` as a list of functions, rather than a new function `f[x]`.

```
func[expr_, var_] := Module[{f, x},
  f = expr /. var -> x;
  Plot[f, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Black}]]

func[{Sin[y], Sin[2 y]}, y]
```

[image]